# ngFor no reconoce variable

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9, ngfor, angular12

Tengo un ng for que recorre un arreglo y muestra los datos de la siguiente manera

```
        <li *ngFor="let item of menuItems" class="nav-devider">
                        <li class="nav-small-cap">{{item.division}}</li>
                    </li>
```

El cual me muestra el siguiente error en la parte del item.division

> Property 'item' does not exist on type 'SidebarComponent'

Mi problema es este el cual no logro hacer que entre mi ngFor, intente cambiar la etiqueta

donde mando a llamar al item.division por otra y lo hace reconoce de manera correcta pero requiero hacer el uso de esa etiqueta en ambas partes donde se llama el ngFor y el item.division

Hice otro ngFor donde si funciono el cual es este

```
                    <li *ngFor="let item of menuItems"> 
                        <a class="has-arrow waves-effect waves-dark" href="#" aria-expanded="false"><i class="mdi mdi-gauge"></i><span class="hide-menu">{{item.titulo}} 
                            <span class="label label-rouded label-themecolor pull-right">{{item.submenu.length}}</span></span></a>
                        <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse">
                            <li *ngFor="let subMenuItem of item.submenu">
                                <a [routerLink]="subMenuItem.url">{{subMenuItem.titulo}} </a>
                            </li>
                          
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

No logro comprender porque no funciona el primer ngFor, se que se repiten pero intente usar otro array con el dato especifico que quiero pero surge el mismo problema

Answer (score 0):

en tu codigo pudieras cambiar esto

```
<li *ngFor="let item of menuItems" class="nav-devider">
   <li class="nav-small-cap">{{item.division}}</li>
 </li>
```

por esto

```
<li *ngFor="let item of menuItems" class="nav-devider">
        {{item.division}}
 </li>
```

no deberias anidar 2 estiquestas `li`

en tu `component.ts` deberias tener el arreglo de datos de `menuItems`

si es un listado numerico deberias definirlo asi

```
<ol>
  <li *ngFor="let item of menuItems" class="nav-devider">
            {{item.division}}
     </li>
</ol>
```

si es un listado de items asi

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of menuItems" class="nav-devider">
            {{item.division}}
     </li>
</ul>
```